# consecutive <li> classes

Tags: php, wordpress, class, on-the-fly

I have trouble finding an expression to automatically generate a new 'class' like the following:

```
<ul>
<li class="img1">link</li>
<li class="img2">link</li>
<li class="img3">link etc...</li>
</ul>
```

This is nested in 2 tabs for 'most read' / 'latest comments'.  The different classes are so that I can make a different bullet (number) using CSS; actually, `<li>` classes are to give a stylized rather than ordinary (bullet) number

I expect I need JavaScript to generate 6 classes to use together with the WordPress calls for latest comments and an RSS feed.

I thought it should be simple stuff to find, but so far zilch of WordPress forums, Google etc.; plus, I have no JavaScript programming background.

I'd appreciate any potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

If it's numbered would you not use an ordered list?  `<ol>`.

Or maybe I'm missing a point here.  Are you using a higher level language to create this html?  or tool?

Comment: Wordpress is PHP, you should be able to tell this straight from the tags of the question, dove.

Comment: @The Wicked Flea eh, i would have but those tags were added afterwards by @Jamie Ide, probably after reading @billnanson comment.

Comment: @Jamie Ide, that's my point, for the wicked flea, before you tags and the other comment, there was no clue it was php as the flea was suggesting I should be able to tell.  no sweat really.

Answer (score 1):

This code will generate the incremental classes:

```
<?
class linkClass
{
        public static $n;
        public function next()
        {
                return self::$n++;
        }
}
?>

<? linkClass::$n = 1; ?>
<ul>
  <li class="link<? print(linkClass::next());?>">link</li>
  <li class="link<? print(linkClass::next());?>">link</li>
  <li class="link<? print(linkClass::next());?>">link</li>
</ul>
```

You would put the "print(linkClass::next());" in the line generating the links such as(not a real example):

```
foreach($links as $link)
  echo '<li class='.linkClass::next().'>'.$link.'</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to either generate the classes server-side, or using javascript if you want them to change at runtime.

Comment: AgileJon,
I want to add an image - so particular number style - doing this with css

Comment: sorry comment was for 'dove' ;-)
Is the a js library where I would find this or could you make a suggestion
Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to print out an unordered list with each list item having a unique class that increases by 1 each time a list item is printed?

I don't have any exprience with Wordpress, but could this not be easily done with a variable that you increase each time a list item is printed?

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="<?php echo "img","$i"; ?>>link</li><?php $i++; ?>
  <li class="<?php echo "img","$i"; ?>>link</li><?php $i++; ?>
  <li class="<?php echo "img","$i"; ?>>link etc...</li><?php $i++; ?>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you could create a function that does the following:
1) Print out the number
2) Increase the value of the number by one so that the next time the function is called it prints out a higher value

This would then allow you to do the following:

```
function classImg() {
  echo "img", "$i";
  $i++;
}

<ul>
  <li class="<?php classImg(); ?>>link</li>
  <li class="<?php classImg(); ?>>link</li>
  <li class="<?php classImg(); ?>>link etc...</li>
</ul>
```

I have written this off the top of my head and so there are probably errors but I hope you understand what I am getting at.

Comment: A simpler version of your first code example is <?php echo "img", $i++ ?>.  You don't need to make the increment separate.

Comment: and your classImg() function isn't going to work since $i isn't scoped global/static

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page):

```
$(function(){
  $('ul.special').each(function() {
    $('li', this).each(function(i) { this.addClass('img'+i.toString()); });
  });
});
```

This is written off the top of my head with the barest reference.  I suggest you check out [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for more information, etc.